# converting schema in XML to XSD for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xsd

Note, I am *not* trying to generate the schema for an XML file from the file.  There is plenty about that on the web.  Kind of a waste--how can a file fail validation if the validator was generated from the file it's validating?

Anyway, I want to test an SSIS component that requires a configuration file in XML (not XSD) to tell it how to parse another input file (this input is also not XML).

The provider of this component says we have to create our own config xml files.  I would like to use Intellisense to help do that.  There is a schema for these config files, but it is in XML.

Is there a way to create a schema from an XML file that represents the **content** of that file, **not** the structure?

Comment: Some examples of what you're talking about would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example is in second paragraph.  Anyway, it turns out there is a way, and it's embarassingly simple.

Just rename the file from `whatever.xml` to `whatever.xsd`